# Oracle: Trouble creating two composite keys

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, composite-key

One of my tables has a composite key comprised of three foreign keys (order_no, product_code and product_size).

In the table where Product_size is the primary key I want to have a composite key consisting of Product_size and product_code. If I do make these a composite key, product_size alone will not be a PK and so I cannot reference it in the creation of the composite key comprised of the three foreign keys.

```
create table product_stock
(
Product_Code varchar2(6) constraint productcode_fk references product(Product_Code),
Product_Size char(1) constraint size_chk check (Product_Size in   
('L', 'l', 'M', 'm', 'S', 's' )),
Product_Unitprice number(7,2) not null,
Stock_Quantity number(4) not null,
constraint prodstock_comp primary key (product_code,product_size)
);


create table orderline
(
Order_No number(4) constraint orderno_fk references order_detail(Order_No),
Product_Code varchar2(6) constraint productcode2_fk references product(Product_Code),
Product_Size char(1) constraint productsize_fk references product_stock(product_size),
Product_Quantity number(4) not null,
constraint orderline_comp primary key (Order_No,Product_Code, Product_Size)
);
```

Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 3):

> product_size alone will not be a PK and so I cannot reference it

Imagine you have two rows in `product_stock` table that have the same `product_size` (and different `product_code`). Now imagine one of these rows (but not the other) is deleted.

- Should that be restricted because there are `orderline` rows that reference it?
- Or should it be allowed because there still exists the other `product_stock` row, that `orderline` rows *also* reference?

*(Similar problems exist for ON DELETE CASCADE / SET NULL and also when UPDATE-ing the PK.)*

To avoid these kinds of ambiguities, the DBMS won't let you create a foreign key unless you can uniquely identify parent row, meaning you must use the **whole** key after the REFERENCES clause of your FK.

---

That being said, you could create both...

```
FOREIGN KEY (product_code)
REFERENCES product (product_code)
```

...and...

```
FOREIGN KEY (product_code, product_size)
REFERENCES product_stock (product_code, product_size)
```

Although, if you have the latter, the former is *probably* redundant.

In fact, (since you already have the FK `product_stock -> product`), having both FKs would create a "diamond shaped" dependency. BTW, some DMBSes have restrictions on diamond-shaped FKs (MS SQL Server doesn't support cascading referential actions on them).

Comment: Are you sure about the "straight forbidden" for SQL-Server? I think only the cascading effects are forbidden in diamond patterns (because of the double path).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your specific DBMS, but you can probably define foreign keys on multiple columns with a separate constraint clause like so:

```
create table orderline (
  Order_No number(4) constraint orderno_fk references order_detail(Order_No),
  Product_Code varchar2(6) constraint productcode2_fk references product(Product_Code),
  Product_Size char(1) constraint productsize_fk references product_stock(product_size),
  Product_Quantity number(4) not null,
  constraint orderline_comp primary key (Order_No,Product_Code, Product_Size),
  constraint fk_product_stock foreign key (product_code, product_size) references product_stock (product_code, product_size)
);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that the composite key consisting of Product_code and product_size should reside in the product_stock table. And that is why I am getting this error. Any thoughts?

Comment: You could then remove the `productcode2_fk` and `productsize_fk` FKs.